# How to get value out of an if statement c++?

Tags: c++, if-statement

How can I get a value from an if statement? What I mean is if the number is more then 151 like in the first if statement. How can I get the value of r1 out of that block, so I can add everything at the end including that specific value from what if statement is chosen.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const double beefMeal = 12.95;
    const double chickenMeal = 10.95;
    const double veganMeal = 8.95;
    int beef, chicken, vegan;
    const int room1 = 250;
    const int room2 = 200;
    const int room3 = 100;
    const int room4 = 50;
    int numParty;
    double r1= 0, r2= 0, r3= 0, r4= 0, b1, c1, v1;
    double grat, total;

    cout <<"Enter number of beef meals: ";
    cin>>beef;
    cout<<endl;
    cout <<"Enter number of chicken meals: ";
    cin>>chicken;
    cout<<endl;
    cout <<"Enter number of vegan meals: ";
    cin >> vegan;
    cout<<""<<endl;

    cout<<"A Caterers Program"<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;

    cout.setf (ios::fixed | ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
    cout<<"Number in party: ";
    cin>> numParty;
    if(numParty>151)
    {
        r1 = (room1 * 6.5)/100;
        cout<<"Room cost:                                           $"<<room1<<endl;
        cout<<"Room tax:                                            $"<<r1<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (numParty <= 150 && numParty >= 100) 
        {
            r2 = (room2 * 6.5)/100;
            cout<<"Room cost:            $"<<room2<<endl;
            cout<<"Room tax:             $"<<r2<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (numParty <= 99 && numParty >= 31)
            {
                r3 = (room3 * 6.5)/100;
                cout<<"Room cost:            $"<<room3<<endl;
                cout<<"Room tax:             $"<<r3<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                if (numParty <= 30)
                {
                    r4 = (room4 * 6.5)/100;
                    cout<<"Room cost:            $"<<room4<<endl;
                    cout<<"Room tax:             $"<<r4<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"Number of beef dinners:    "<<beef<<endl;
    b1 = beef * beefMeal; 
    cout<<"Cost of beef dinners:               $"<<b1<<endl;
    cout<<"Number of chicken dinners: "<<chicken<<endl;
    c1 = chicken * chickenMeal; 
    cout<<"Cost of chicken dinners:            $"<<c1<<endl;
    cout<<"Number of vegan dinners:   "<<vegan<<endl;
    v1 = vegan * veganMeal; 
    cout<<"Cost of vegan dinners:              $"<<v1<<endl;
    grat = (b1 + c1 + v1) * 0.18;
    cout<<"Food Gratuity:                      $"<<grat<<endl;

    cout<<"________________________________________________"<<endl;
    total = grat + v1 + c1 + b1 + r1 + r2 + r3 + r4;
    cout<<"Total: $"<< total;
}
```

Comment: Your close, just give your variables a default value (most likely 0.0)  and then you can use them at the end of your if else checks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you declared the variables `r1,r2...` at the outermost scope they are valid and accessible at any scopes inside the outer scope.

Comment: Note that you should initialize your variables if you want to use them outside of the if: double r1=0,r2=0, etc.

Comment: Im sorry I think I didnt get across what I meant I reposted my code above.

Comment: @edolloff: What is the problem you are facing? the code seems correct.

Comment: Im just trying to get my total at the end to come out with r1, r2, r3, r4... if selected @joe

Comment: so if total = grat + v1 + c1 + b1 + r1 + r2 + r3 + r4;
and say the if statement with r1 is chosen it shows at the end of the code. @Als

Comment: @edolloff: Yes and they way you are doing is okay, If it was not then you wuold have got an compilation error.

Comment: It does compile its just that when adding the total amount of everything the room values are not being added into it which is what i want

Comment: @edolloff: The code looks correct, Make sure the control goes within the conditional loops by putting some prints or by debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is the body of some function and all those double variables are local variables for that function which means they are visible within its scope. Regarding this, you don't need to do anything special, just make sure they are properly initialized and/or assigned values.

```
void foo()
{
   double r1 = 0;

   if(some_condition)
   {
       // use r1...
   }
   else
   {
      // use r1...
   }

   // use r1...        
}
```